# Recreate Java Process Object from known PID

Tags: java, process, pid, processbuilder, process-monitoring

I have a program (Process Monitor of some sort) that launches multiple programs with a ProcessBuilder. When I start this ProcessBuilder (for each program), I can start it and it will give me a Process object. With this Process object in memory, I can even stop my programs with destroy() or destroyForcibly().

Now, if my main program (Process Monitor) were to crash, and I restart it, and let's also say I have a the PID of each program I launched, how could I recreate a Process object with this PID ? I don't see the option in the Process class, or in ProcessBuilder (even though I guess we would need a ProcessLoader instead of a Builder).

Is there any way to do that?

To illustrate what I want:

```
long pid = getPid();
Process process = new Process(pid);
//or
Process process = new Process();
process.load(pid);
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know the OS assigns the PID so unless the OS allows you to define a custom pid (I doubt there is such an option) you just can't do that. Btw, what are you actually trying to achieve? Why don't you just create another process with a different PID in case of a crash?

Comment: The thing is, my process monitor can crash but that wouldn't mean my other programs would crash too, so when I restart my process monitor, I'd like to see the statuses of my programs directly, without having the need to restart all of them. 
I'd love to do something like Process process = new Process(pid); that would just link an existing process in the OS to the java object Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if someone ever needs something like me, he can actually use ProcessHandle

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html

```
long pid = getPid();
ProcessHandle process;
Optional<ProcessHandle> possibleProcess = ProcessHandle.of(pid);
if(possibleProcess.isPresent()) process = possibleProcess.get();
```

You get a Stream than you can either collect or manipulate further if you wish, and a ProcessHandle handle the same set of operation as a Process (onExit(), destroy(), destroyForcibly(), etc.)